# knowledge-api maven version don't have new version?

Tags: drools

`knowledge-api` maven version don't have new version?
What is the impact will be if other drools libraries upgraded to 7?

Answer (score 3):

As new versions of Drools are released, some Jars are end-of-life'd as their functionality is either subsumed into other jars or no longer supported.

The `knowledge-api` jar was a part of Drools 6.x, but is not part of Drools 7. This is logical since it was intended to be an adapter from the Drools 5 `drools-api` jar to the KIE APIs. Since the adapter's purpose was to facilitate backwards compatibility for the previous release, it makes sense it wasn't included in Drools 7 at all, since everything relying on the Drools 5 functionality should have been long since upgraded.

At least for this particular library ...

| Version | Jar |
| --- | --- |
| Drools 5 | drools-api |
| Drools 6 | knowledge-api |
| Drools 7 | kie-api |

... though note that these jars are likely *not* drop-in replacements depending on what you're using from the library itself. The package names and class names usually change between major releases.

Comment: If you're concerned about something specific in this jar that you're relying on that no longer functions post upgrade to Drools 7, please open a new question specifically describing what you're using in Drools 6 and what happens when you try to upgrade to the Drools 7 equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 2):

`knowledge-api` was replaced by `kie-api`